# use servlet to develop a proxy server

Tags: java, servlets, proxy

I'm using servlet to build a proxy serve. I parse some hyperlink like

```
a href="http://www.google.com"
```

to

```
a href="proxyserver?url=http://www.google.com"
```

form, frame , iframe is also parsed by me. So all the request will through my proxy server. But now I find some problems.

For example: Like "form" tag..

javascript will process the form's action. It changed the action. It's so terrible.

How can I do? Are there any better methods?

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting pages like this is really hard.  Been there ... never really succeeded.

I think that you would be better off writing a (trusted) browser plugin that does the proxying by intercepting and rewriting the out-going HTTP requests.  (And I'm not even sure THAT is possible ...)

Comment: Well then you will just have to do the best that you can, and accept that pages the use javascript to create URLs or send requests are liable to break.